# getSpeed() of Location is not working on WiFi

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-location

I want to calculate the speed of user on WiFi. I am getting location updates via. onLocationChanged() but every time **hasSpeed()** returning false and **getSpeed()** returning 0.0.

Is there any API available to get speed on WiFi or I need to calculate speed manually? Any help or guidance will be well appreciated.

**Note**: I am able to get the speed on GPS.

Comment: Bro wifi doesn't give u speed ...so every time getSpeed(); will return you 0.00 float value

Comment: Hi Mann, thanks for the quick reply. Your conclusion is Speed calculations are done by GPS transmitters/receivers, right?

Comment: Yup and only GPS Satellite gives u the accuracy,altitude and speed

Comment: Thanks, I got the answer. Just for information, I am able to get the accuracy with WiFi also.

Comment: I believe Android will report an accuracy regardless of the location information type. It's a different system for calculating that accuracy on WiFi versus with GPS, of course, but it'll still take a guess at its accuracy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use `getSpeed()` when the user is only connected to WiFi. WiFi location works based on known locations of networks the phone sees. Unlike GPS, this will only ever provide a rough location, so there's no way to calculate speed.

Think about it like this: If I start at point A and walk 10 feet to point B, will there be any chance in the WiFi networks I can see? Probably not. Will be there be a change in my GPS coordinates? With a decent view of the sky, yes.

Comment: Hi Computerish, thanks for the reply. Then on WiFi, I need to calculate the speed based on the location updates, right?

Comment: You simply won't be able to obtain an accurate speed reading unless your user is travelling fast enough to be passing lots of hotspots. Perhaps if the user were driving down a road with lots of nearby WiFi networks you could get a rough average based on location updates. I suspect in this case Android might even report a `getSpeed()` value, but I wouldn't expect it to be very accurate and in most situations the location simply won't change.